# Call other Fragment from dropDown of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, drop-down-menu, navigation, android-actionbar

In my app I have added a DropDown Spinner in ActionBar and now am not able to make out - how to change the bottom part on each drop down selected. In my activity_main.xml layout (Home), contains only a Fragment that shows a list. I am looking for is, to create other UI screens also as Fragment and change the placed Fragment on every dropDown selected. I mean Home page has fragment_main.xml, dropDown setting is selected then show setting_fragment.xml and so on. My main is :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="terryconsulting.servicestation.AppointListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

In MainActivity class, I have implemented `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` which called earlier PlaceholderFragment that just showed Hello World text on the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.
    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    //        .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
    //        .commit();
    return true;
    // http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html --- ACTIONBAR ACTION
}

// As AppointListFragment is added in this activity, so need to implement this listener here
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    System.out.println("Into onFragmentInteraction. URL - " + uri);

    return;
}
```

WHERE I AM STUCK :- I am not able to make out how to call/set `SettingFragment` when setting is selected from drop down. And from setting when `Home` icon is pressed go back to home page with `AppointListFragment` on it ???

What I am thinking & asking of, is it possible & practical ? I think it should be, as calling Setting as an Activity with its own `ActionBar` would not be best solution.

Please guide me with this, I have searched many tutorials but couldn't find this situation or examples with NavigationSelection & Fragments any where.

Answer (score 1):

fragments in XML layouts are meant to be static ones. I'm pretty it's possible somehow to make them work, but for dynamic generated/created/removed you want to do everything in Java.

said that, first you remove the `<fragment` from your XML, then on your activity creation:

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(... your xml layout ... );

```
   // fragments are auto-re-created on rotation,
   // so only create/put in layout one if not rotating
   if(savedInstanceState == null){

       // I'm assuming here your first fragment is position 0
       gotoFragment(0);
   }
```

}

then on each selection is just call to the new one:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    gotoFragment(position);
    return true;
}
```

and here is the general method to change the fragments on the screen.

```
private void gotoFragment(int position){
       Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("position_" + position);
       if(f == null){
           switch(position){
               case values:
                  f = // create here new object of your fragment for each position
           }
       }

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, f, "position_" + position)
                .commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Budius. Above code helped me a lot. But am facing a problem with onCreate code. As I have Home enabled in ActionBar & am also adding the fragment (position_0) to be added on home page, I have not added Home in my dropDown. Navigation selects 1st element by default in 'onCreate' every time, so on start I see my 0th fragment (position_0) & immediately 1st fragment (position_1). I tried 'actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(-1);', but yet it makes no difference. I wish not to add Home in drop down as Home icon click is already their. Any idea how can I overcome this problem !!

Comment: And when Home Is selected, nothing should be visible on dropdown selected item.